# What is a G2K company?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is a G2K company? I assume G2K does not mean *[good to know](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/g2k)*.

> [SMB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_and_medium_businesses)/[SME](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/g2k) companies don't have the resources to hire 1-3 social managers, incorporate listening and engaging platforms like a G2K company.

[Context](http://www.quora.com/Social-Networks/What-is-lacking-in-social-networking-now/answer/Lee-Traupel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Forbes Global 2000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forbes_Global_2000)

2K as in 2000—Like the Y2K bug